# Setting up a variable in setInterval(), react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to setup a pause variable inside `setInterval()` function, after few times pressing button pause it became to act weirdly, it's not same like outer variable. What i'm doing wrong?
Run code snippet, and press pause few times

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React
        
        function App() {
          const [pause, setPause] = useState(false)
          const [innerVar, setInnerVar] = useState(false)
          const [outerVar, setOuterVar] = useState(false)
          useEffect(()=>{
            setOuterVar(pause)
          }, [pause])
        
          const interval = setInterval(function() {
            setInnerVar(pause) 
          }, 2000)
        
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setPause(!pause)}>Pause</button>
              <div>Pause variable: {pause ? 'true': 'false'}</div>
              <div>Inside setInteval: {innerVar ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
              <div>Outside setInterval: {outerVar ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
          </div>
          )
        }
        
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? when innerVar should be changed?
Currently, you're changing it every 2 seconds to the same value and whenever the component is rendered a new interval is created, this is why you see a "weird" behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're not clearing the interval.

2) According to your code, a new interval is set each time the component is rendered.

Set the interval in `useEffect` so that it is consistent with when the `pause` value changes and then clear the interval in the clean-up function.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React
        
        function App() {
          const [pause, setPause] = useState(false)
          const [innerVar, setInnerVar] = useState(false)
          const [outerVar, setOuterVar] = useState(false)
          useEffect(()=>{
            setOuterVar(pause);
            const interval = setInterval(function() {
              setInnerVar(pause) 
            }, 2000);
            return ()=>{clearInterval(interval);};
          }, [pause]);
        
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setPause(!pause)}>Pause</button>
              <div>Pause variable: {pause ? 'true': 'false'}</div>
              <div>Inside setInteval: {innerVar ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
              <div>Outside setInterval: {outerVar ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
          </div>
          )
        }
        
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

From @Alexfrostwolf answer, you don't really need setInterval in this case now and use setTimeout instead. Though, will leave my answer with minimum modification from you code.

Comment: So, setInterval() doesn't check if variable is changed before runs the function? Is it possible not to re render or restart setInterval(), but continuously run it with different variable values? So if runs first time with => var willChange=false, next time if willChenge=true , just to run with true value...?

Comment: Your component will always rerender whenever `setPause` is called. That's how react hooks work. useEffect is always called when the component is rerendered, so it does the same thing you want to achieve with set interval if you're trying to use setInterval to update the value if pause is changed.

Comment: One more question :)
What if I don't change variable using hooks, but it comes from redux, for example, and what i'm doing inside setInterval() is sending request to backend. So I want to skip sending new request if previous request is not finished, and i know it's not finished by loading indicator that is coming from redux, like: const isDataLoading = useSelector(state => state.portal.isLoadingData). The problem is that outside setInterval() valiable changes, but inside doesn't. How to fix that?

Comment: If the component is connected to a redux store and the value is changed, it'll rerender. If you want to make the api request only once, then you can do that is componentDidMount same as useEffect with empty dependancy array. You'll have to work out the logic if you want to make request only if there is no API request pending. Maybe use componentWillReceiveProps or useRef in case of hooks.